# What's the best way to duplicate the "action bar" found in the Play Store?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Should I just remove the actionbar and create a custom view fragment? I'm assuming there is nothing standard that does this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a search view and there's a library for that

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch